# Meteor Blaze - Differentiating Between Classes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

In my current project the user can create a post and each post is iterated on a page.

I run into the problem of conflicting classes.

I have a checkbox that has the class `attend` however it conflicts with other posts and with the `'click .attend'` function I created.

Is there any way to create a unique class for each post?

I have tried doing:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" class="{{this._id}}" checked="" />
```

but the function doesn't allow

```
'click .this._id'
```

I am stuck on what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are going about it in slightly the wrong way.  You can have the same class, but what you need to is to put a template for each post.  That template can easily get to the correct class for each of the instances of that template.

```
    <head>
  <title>demosub</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> allposts}}

</body>
<template name="allposts">
   {{#each posts}}
      {{> thepost }}
   {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="thepost">
   <div>
     <span>{{_id}}</span>
      <input type="checkbox" class="attend" checked="" />
    </div>
</template>
```

then in your event code for the template 'thepost'

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';


Template.allposts.helpers({
  posts() {
    return [{_id: 1}, {_id: 2}]
  },
});

Template.thepost.events({
  'click .attend': function(e,t){
    var data = Template.instance().data  // this is your post...
    console.log(e.toElement.checked)
    console.log(data)
  }
})
```

below you can see where I click on each of the check box and how it knows which post it is clicked on :-

[image]

The template event knows that click event on the class "attend" is associated with an instance of the template and calls that event handler.

Comment: I already have it set up as the first part.  However, I do not fully understand the second portion of your code!

Comment: which bit,  the event?

Comment: Yeah that part.

Comment: I've edited with actual working code and an example of what happens when you click the check boxes

Comment: I see what you mean now, so just include the checked code inside its own event!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a class for each post. Take a look at [Meteor todos tutorial - update & remove](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/update-and-remove)

This could be your HTML input

```
<input type="checkbox" class="yourcheckboxclass" checked="{{checked}}"/>
```

This could be your Javascript code

```
'change [type=checkbox]': function(e, tpl) {
     // Here you can access your post data with 'this' and use it 
     // to do what you want.
     console.log(this._id)
     }
```

*NOTE: Don't use `id="check"` for each post because you will have several items with the same ID in your HTML.*